# Does Wasm require validation of locals set before accessed?

Tags: webassembly

From a famous Wasm article [WebAssembly Troubles part 1: WebAssembly Is Not a Stack Machine](http://troubles.md/wasm-is-not-a-stack-machine/), it wrote that

> In WebAssembly as it exists now, you have to zero locals when entering a function unless you can statically prove that the local is always set before it is accessed.

This article was written in 2019, and for now, I wonder if this still holds. So I write a WASM file:

```
(module
    (func (export "get_before_set") (result i32)
        (local $dummy i32)
        local.get $dummy
    )
)
```

I run this WASM file with wasmer, and it turns out that this function just returns 0.

Does this mean that, WebAssembly require **engine** (instead of manually) to zero locals unless **engine** can statically prove that local is set before accessed?

I went through the WASM specification, and didn't find record about this requirement. Does this behavior a standard, or just implementation-defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantically, yes. Though of course, in practice, if an engine sees that a local's initialisation value is never read before being overwritten, it is totally free to optimise away the default initialisation.

As for where this is specified, it's [here](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/exec/instructions.html#function-calls), when constructing the function frame.

That being said, the upcoming [function references proposal](https://github.com/WebAssembly/function-references) introduces the notion of uninitialised locals and validates that they are not read. But that only applies to locals of types that do not have a default value, like non-null references.